# Compiler programming languages theory, computer usable computing and I/O parts

Tags: user-interface, io, computation, windowing, peripherals

I started with a small theory of cmd and extensions. First of all was that it consists of compilation to object file, linkage and compilation to exe. The languages mainly consist of operators, keywords and directives which is compiled into machine code with directives, keywords and from library assembler of functions. What else plays a role?

Than there is cmd, standard I/O and windowing (with graphics modes), the normal interface consists of minimize, exit and maximize/restore down and panel with started programs. There could be text inputs (passwords), radio, checkbox and buttons (for menus). What else is there in GUI?

Cmd also include command line parameters. What else could be called before?

The useable parts of computer in libraries is harddisk CPU GPU, memories of graphic card and processor.
From peripherals the normal input parts is mouse keyboard cd/dvd-rom usb and networking card. May have videocamera and microphone.
The outputs is monitor and speakers, cd dvd usb and networking card.
Both is movement/vibrations monitoring. (not normal)
What else is normally installed?

Comment: No, I am collecting info and thinking about what i can code

Comment: Is this is some alternative brainstorming technique to produce the next killer app?